# How to query array from a querybuild in AdonisJs?

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

I have an object whose column refers to a Json type.

How do I perform a query inside the Json column using id for example?

Model

```
 @column({
    prepare: (value: Array<object>) => JSON.stringify(value),
    consume: (value: string) => JSON.parse(value),
  })
  public armazenado: object
```

Controller

```
const items = await Armazempredio.query().select('*')
      .with('armazenado', builder => {
        builder.where(Database.raw(`JSON_CONTAINS(id, '["0001"]')`))
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolver with

```
@column({
    prepare: (value: Array<object>) => JSON.stringify(value),
    consume: (value: string) => JSON.parse(value),
  })
```